# How to transfer data from ajax to a laravel 5.2 controller via the mail method

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to transfer data to the controller using ajax. Here is the ajax code

```
$(document).on("click", '#bt1', function(e)
{
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         url:"/insert_",
         type:"post",
         data:{
             name2:"admin",
             _token: $("input[name='_token']").val()
         }
     })
});
```

Here is the code in the controller

```
public function insert_db(Request $request)
{
    $a1=$request->input("name2");
    dd($a1);
}
```

Here is the layout code

```
<form action="/insert_" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit" id="bt1" value="do it">
</form>
```

Вот код в web.php

```
Route::post('/insert_',"StudentController@insert_db");
```

But display null.
Help please

Answer (score 0):

Change your route method get to post,

```
Route::post('/insert_',"Insert_db@insert_data");
```

And in your form,

```
<form action="/insert_" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit" id="bt1" value="do it">
</form>
```

Your ajax request function,

```
$(document).on("click", '#bt1', function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
   url:"/insert_",
   type:"post",      // change method to type and type is post
   data:{
       name2:"admin",
       // make sure you add csrf token
       _token: $("input[name='_token']").val(),
   }
});
```

Comment: i changed all, but i have stiil problem. Displays null

Comment: wait, i will make a new question and i will show you

Comment: i used your code, but still displays null. Now i will show

Comment: i changed all code in my question, look at this again, please. Displays null